# What is the group _appstore, and why are large number of files in this group?

Tags: macos, permission, filesystem

What is the group _appstore?

I have a folder with quite a few files in it. Until recently, the files would have had ownerhip of jas:staff, where jas is my username.

I noticed recently that many files have the group changed to _appstore. Here is an extract of a listing showning both types:

```
-r--rw----  1 jas  _appstore    17914 Jul 16  2010 zenda-left-pic-152x472x60.jpg
-r--rw----  1 jas  _appstore      994 Jul 16  2010 zenda-logo-129x23x24.gif
-r--rw----  1 jas  _appstore     5692 Jul 16  2010 zenda-rolls-128x126x60.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 jas  staff          275 Jun  1  2007 k-t-industries_bullet-20x18.gif
-rw-r--r--  1 jas  staff        19901 Jun  1  2007 k-t-industries-1-420x179x40.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 jas  staff         2400 Jun  1  2007 k-t-industries_logo-140x81x32.gif
```

There are about 1525 files in this directory and over 1500 have the 460 jas:_appstore, instead of the expected 644 jas:staff.